# Slideshow of web pages (html slideshow)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow, slide

I am trying to make slideshow of dynamically created web (html) pages. I managed to make browsing to previous and next page using clicking on links or using keyboard buttons (left/right arrows). I just need to put `id="prev"` and `id="next"` on link I wish to be to previous or next page.
Also I use jQuery and after jQuery is loaded I load this script too.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var keymap = {};
    
 // LEFT
 keymap[ 37 ] = "#prev";
 // RIGHT
 keymap[ 39 ] = "#next";
    
 $(document).on("keyup", function(event) {
   var href,
     selector = keymap[event.which];
   // if the key pressed was in our map, check for the href
   if ( selector ) {
     href = $(selector).attr("href");
     if (href) {
       // navigate where the link points
       window.location = href;
     }
   }
 });
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="prev" href="/dynamic-prev-link-here">prev</a>
<a id="next" href="/dynamic-next-link-here">next</a>
```

Now, I am thinking to make slideshow function too, it could be with or without keyboard support, even click on some link/button would be fine.

For example, when some link/button is clicked/pressed to start slideshow, to open link with id="prev", and when next page is loaded to wait for about 5 second and to open again link with id="next", and so on.

Is it possible to include it in current script or with some other java script?

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you don't use something like [reveal.js](http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/)?

Comment: If you can provide example related to my html, that would be great. I looked at their presentation. I am not sure is that slide show inside one page or between pages (diferent URLs)?